# How to determine if postgres database contains GiST indexes and what type?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, gist-index

Is there a way to easily check if a PostgreSQL database has any GiST indexes and of what type they are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you need to examine the structure of your database via code, always think "I should look at `information_schema` or `pg_catalog`". `information_schema` contains a standardized schema (66 views), whereas `pg_catalog` is PostgreSQL-specific, but contains more info (97 tables or views).

```
select 
  * 
from
  pg_catalog.pg_indexes 
where 
  indexdef ~* '\ygist\y'
```

Will show you all the gist indexes and their tables, names, and definitions.

`~*` means match a regular expression, case-insensitive.

`\y` means word boundary, so it would find ' gist ' but not 'logistics' in that column

Comment: Thanks!  This worked!  The command did not produce any results, but that was somewhat expected as most of our indexes are btree.